# Installing node js and npm on Vanilla os

Tags: node.js, linux

I'm trying to install node js and npm on vanilla os. I've tried flatpak install method as well but it didn't work. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/, https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ There's nothing in the question anyone can use to help. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning to use nodejs on top of Visual Studio Code (installed as a Flatpak) then the version you installed from Flathub is fine but you need to change the environment variables of Code to detect that SDK. To do this:

```bash
flatpak override --user --env=FLATPAK_ENABLE_SDK_EXT=* com.visualstudio.code
```

this will enable/expose any SDK you install via Flatpak.

---

If instead your aim is to use it outside the Flatpak context, you can install the [nodejs](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/nodejs) package from the Ubuntu repository using `apx`, the distribution's package manager:

```bash
apx install nodejs
```

You can get a more recent version installing it from the Fedora or Arch Linux repository, using the `--dnf` (for Fedora) or `--aur` (for Arch linux), so:

```bash
apx install --dnf nodejs
# or
apx install --aur nodejs
```

Then to use it you can proceed with one of the following methods:

**entering the Apx container**

```bash
apx enter
# or apx --dnf enter
# or apx --aur enter
# then
npm ...
```

**using the `run` option**

```bash
apx run npm ..
# or apx --dnf run npm ..
# or apx --aur run npm ..
```

---

It is also possible (but not recommended) to install nodejs directly on the host system. To do this you need to use the [`abroot`](https://documentation.vanillaos.org/docs/ABRoot/) command which allows you to create an [atomic transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing) which can make changes to the system:

```bash
sudo abroot exec apt install nodejs
```

it will ask you to reboot to apply the changes (if the transaction succeed).

Comment: I's able to install and use node using apx commands. But my visual codes extensions are not working moreover in vs code terminal the node commands are also not working with apx as well!

Comment: If Code was installed via Apx it should work. Code and Node must be on the same platform.

Comment: Thanks Mirko, your advise was really helpful. After going through the vanilla os docs I'm able to install vs code using apx and hence node js is also accessible in the IDE terminal now.